# Login Items -> Launch in 32-bit mode?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I've noticed that any apps that support both 32-bit and 64-bit mode, even when set to start in 32-bit mode, will always default to 64-bit mode when launched on login. In other words, launching the app from Finder will correctly load it up in 32-bit mode, but it will not do this if I then add it to the Login Items list for my user under System Preferences.

Does anyone have some insight into how I might achieve this? Maybe add a shell script to the login items list that calls "arch -i386 [app-binary]" ?

Comment: Does `open` honor the architecture setting?

Comment: Good question, let me verify and I'll update what I find... (Update: yes, `open` does honor the architecture setting.)

Comment: Posted a workaround using `open`. I don't know how to determine a running application's architecture setting, so I can't test it myself. Please let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create a wrapper application to `open` using Automator or AppleScript Editor.

---

In Automator, create a new *Application*.

Add the *Run Shell Script* step from the library and set the following script contents:

```
open -a "App Name"
```

Save as e.g. *Run App Name i386.app* and add this program to your Login Items.

Using `open` means it immediately quits, so it doesn't pollute your Dock for long.